# Multiple parameters for the JE instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

This question is in regards to the JE assembly instruction.
Often in explanations of JE, people only pass in one parameter. **I do not have a question about that.**  My question is on when JE is used with multiple parameters (specifically two). Here is an example:

```
 8048f73:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 8048f75:       74 05                   je     8048f7c <phase_1+0x22>
```

My understanding of these two lines extend to this: first you test if eax is equal to zero (essentially) and if it is, then jump to the instruction at 8048f7c (which is a leave instruction). What I don't understand is what the `<phase_1+0x22>`part is doing. My current understanding of these instructions is probably not correct, so would someone clarify what the JE instruction does when given multiple inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `je` instruction there only has 1 argument, the branch address. The `<phase_1+0x22>` is just a friendly service from your disassembler, it's trying to show a human readable form of the numeric address. In this case that means address `8048f7c` is `0x22` bytes past the label `phase_1`. You can check that in gdb if you do `p/a phase_1+0x22`.

PS: If you have doubts about any instruction, first check the instruction set reference.